# how to execute function that dependent on 2 observables

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I'm having a function that needs to get 2 responses from 2 separate async functions (return observables).
1. Func1 return observable
2. Func2 return observable
They are not dependent one on another - they can run separately.
Func 3 should have some how the result of both Func1 and Func2 to execute.
I'm workign with RXJS, and tried doing it using pipe and flatMap or map, but still - didn't managed.

Comment: You need **[`forkJoin`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html)** for this.

Comment: ... or eventually `merge`, `combineLatest`, `zip` depending on what you want to do.

Comment: I would recommand looking at this link https://reactive.how/combinelatest

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need [**`forkJoin`**](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html) for this. Here give this a try:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getGoogle() {
    return this.http.get('https://api.github.com/users/google');
  }

  getMicrosoft() {
    return this.http.get('https://api.github.com/users/microsoft');
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    forkJoin(
      this.getGoogle(),
      this.getMicrosoft()
    )
    .subscribe(
      res => console.log(res)
    )
  }

}
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/fork-join-eg?file=src/app/app.component.ts) for your ref.